# Statistics conferences?

Tags: conferences

What are the most significant annual Statistics conferences?

Rules:

1. One conference per answer
2. Include a link to the conference

Answer (score 7):

UseR!

- [List of previous and upcoming R conferences on r-project](https://www.r-project.org/conferences/)

Related Links:

- [2011: University of Warwick, Coventry, UK](http://www.warwick.ac.uk/statsdept/useR-2011/)
- [Videos of some keynote speakers from 2010](http://www.r-bloggers.com/RUG/?p=180)

Comment: The www.r-project.org/useR-20xx  URLs are preferable.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. I added the link to R conferences on R-project

Answer (score 6):

For biostatistics the largest US conferences are the meetings of the local sections of the International Biometrics Society (IBS):

- [ENAR for the Eastern region](https://www.enar.org/meetings/)
- [WNAR for the Western region](https://wnarofibs.wildapricot.org/Meetings)

Of these ENAR is by far larger.

Answer (score 5):

Shameless plug: [R/Finance](http://www.RinFinance.com) which relevant for its intersection of domain-specifics as well as tools, and so far well received by participants of the 2009 and 2010 conference. .

Disclaimer: I am one of the organizers.

Answer (score 5):

In terms of overall breadth, I would say that the ASA/IMS Joint Statistical Meetings are the most significant.  Next year, the statisticians are taking their talents to South Beach...or [Miami Beach](http://www.amstat.org/meetings/jsm/2011/index.cfm) is more correct.  I just couldn't help to use that line from Lebron James' infamous press conference.  Having said that, I prefer smaller conferences like the UseR! conferences, ICORS (robust statistics), etc.

Answer (score 2):

The main regular conference in Australia is the "Australian Statistics Conference", held every second year. The next one is [ASC 2010](http://www.promaco.com.au/2010/asc/), to be held in Western Australia in December.

Answer (score 2):

This is a new annual conference that should be great for people using statistics and wanting to improve their practical knowledge.  And it will be in warm places in the winter!

The inaugural ASA Conference on Statistical Practice, to be held in Orlando,
Florida, February 16–18, 2012, meets the needs of statistical practitioners
engaged in design, analysis, programming, and consulting. The program for
Statistical Practice 2012 features three main tracks:

- Research and Development, Engineering, and Operations
- Business Analytics
- Communications, Impact, and Career Development

Both the content and format of this conference have been carefully planned to
improve your effectiveness as a statistical problem solver. Invited sessions,
tutorials, and short courses will refresh your statistical training, update
your knowledge of emerging areas of practice, and sharpen your soft skills.
Poster sessions will give you the opportunity to share and discuss your work.
And if you are looking for employment, a virtual career placement service
will benefit your search.

The timing for this conference could not be better, because the opportunities
for statistical practitioners have never been greater.

For more information please visit
http://www.amstat.org/meetings/csp/2012/index.cfm

Answer (score 1):

Though it hasn't been around for decades, I'm currently looking forward to [MCMSki](http://madison.byu.edu/mcmski/).  One could also mention the [Valencia Meetings](http://www.uv.es/valenciameeting), but those only happen every four years (and you've already missed the 2010 meeting).

Comment: Unfortunately, the Valencia meetings are no more. The last one was this year! Instead, we're just going to have general ISBA meetings.

Comment: Oh!  I didn't know.  Crap.

Comment: yeah Dr. Bernardo has apparently told others that he is too old to take care of the valencia conference. He wants young guns to take care of it now.

Answer (score 1):

Joint Statistical Meetings (JSM) is the biggest meeting I know of. In fact it's almost shocking that after 10 years and as many answers, no one else has offered JSM as a possible "best" conference. But "best" boils down to why you're there.

JSM has 1,000s of statisticians, and many industry sponsors, and top tier keynotes from industry and academic leaders. There's too much to do, from round tables, panel discussions, seminars, workshops, job booths, etc. I never went as a graduate student, but wish I did.

https://www.amstat.org/meetings/joint-statistical-meetings

Comment: Because this is already listed in the answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/1913/919, it would be better for you to edit that answer to include any additional information you would like to add.

Answer (score 0):

Not a "statistics" conference in the technical sense, but Predictive Analytics World is a case study conference on how companies are using predictive and other analytics in theis businesses.

[Predictive Analytics World](http://www.predictiveanalyticsworld.com/)

Comment: May fit better under: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1906/data-mining-conferences?

Comment: @Shane, I guess so. I hadn't seen the other two conference questions before I answered.

Answer (score 0):

[ACM SIGKDD 2010](http://www.kdd.org/kdd2010/index.shtml)

[KDD 2011 in San Diego](http://kdd.org/kdd/2011/)

Comment: Already noted here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1906/data-mining-conferences

Answer (score 0):

These have reasonably a comprehensive list of upcoming statistics events.

[Statistics Conferences Worldwide](https://conferencealerts.com/topic-listing?topic=Statistics)

[IMS meetings calender](https://imstat.org/meetings-calendar/)

[Conferences and Meetings on Probability and Statistics](http://www.conference-service.com/conferences/probability-and-statistics.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is an upcoming regular conference, that is being held in Sydney, Australia in July 2012, normally the meetings are in Europe: [8th international conference on social science methodology](http://conference.acspri.org.au/index.php/rc33/2012/index).

The [Australian Consortium for Social and Political Research Inc](http://www.acspri.org.au/) has a conference based in Australia every two years, the one for this year happens to be run combined with the conference I linked above.

Answer (score 0):

for statistics in application to educational and psychological measurement, two of the big name north american conferences are the annual meetings for:

- the [national council on measurement in education](https://www.ncme.org/event/annual-meeting) (hosted in
  vancouver, british columbia, canada); and
- the [psychometric
  society](https://www.psychometricsociety.org/imps2023-schedule) (lincoln, nebraska)