# Data mining conferences?

Tags: data-mining, conferences

What are the most significant annual Data Mining conferences?

Rules:

1. One conference per answer
2. Include a link to the conference

Comment: I downvoted this because it encourages uninformative one-line answers, leading merely to a collection of links with little additional value.  If respondents were to explain, even briefly, *why* their proposed conferences were "significant," this thread would have tremendously greater value.

Comment: Plus, it is completely redundant to the known rankings of such conferences. For example Microsoft Academic: http://academic.research.microsoft.com/RankList?entitytype=3&topDomainID=2&subDomainID=7&last=0&start=1&end=100

Comment: Oh, and third, people here probably don't make the **distinction** between *machine-learning*, *artificial intelligence* and *data mining* (which *does* include data management aspects and only *uses* ML and AI). Just because it's popular to call ML also "data mining" doesn't make this sensible.

Answer (score 7):

[KDD](https://web.archive.org/web/20100701205656/http://www.sigkdd.org/conferences.php) (ACM Special Interest Group on Knowledge Discovery and Data Mining)

- [KDD 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20101201172901/http://www.sigkdd.org/kdd2010/)

Answer (score 5):

NIPS:  http://nips.cc/

Comment: I don't think NIPS is a really a data mining conference, it is a machine learning and (decreasingly) computational neuroscience conference.

Answer (score 4):

[Strata Conference](http://strataconf.com/public/content/home):

> Strata Conference is for developers, data scientists, data analysts,
>   and other data professionals.
>
> Strata Conference covers the latest and best tools and technologies
>   for this new discipline, along the entire data supply chain—from
>   gathering, cleaning, analyzing, and storing data to communicating data
>   intelligence effectively. With hardcore technical sessions, case
>   studies, and provocative reports from the leading edge, Strata
>   Conference showcases the people, tools, and technologies that make big
>   data work.

Not sure I'd quite classify Strata as "data mining" (perhaps "how to use data in the industry", instead), but data mining is certainly a part of it.

Comment: +1 for two reasons: first, it is the only reply (so far) to explain the merits of its nomination, and second, despite the barrage of vague business-speak in the blurb ("data supply chain," "data intelligence," "hardcore," "leading edge"), a look at the conference schedule, the topics, and the presenters reveals the involvement of substantial, serious players from government (NASA, e.g.) as well as industry.  It's very top-heavy in presentations from software and services purveyors, though, suggesting an orientation toward marketing commercial solutions.

Answer (score 2):

SIAM's [Data Mining Conference](http://www.siam.org/meetings/sdm11/), SDM11.

Answer (score 2):

[Salford Analytics and Data Mining Conference 2012](https://web.archive.org/web/20120111153751/http://www.salforddatamining.com/index.php).

Answer (score 2):

IEEE International Conference on Data Mining ([ICDM](http://www.cs.uvm.edu/~icdm/))

Answer (score 1):

M2010 - 13th Annual Data Mining Conference http://www.sas.com/m2010

Answer (score 1):

Predictive Analytics World: [pawcon.com](http://www.predictiveanalyticsworld.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Check this useful site: [AIStats](https://web.archive.org/web/20120303071919/https://aistats.org/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

Industrial Conference on Data Mining [IndustrialDM](http://www.data-mining-forum.de/)